# ASUS Battery Health Charging enabled - but the battery % keeps growing

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

My laptop has ASUS Battery Health Charging and Maximum Lifespan Mode enabled, keeping my battery at 60% charged. However, this was some four weeks ago. Now it's 65%, and it keeps growing.

Am I to assume that this is due to the fact that it takes time for the ASUS app to launch when I turn on the laptop, giving the battery time to charge in the meanwhile? Little by little, it starts adding up.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I have the some issue. I've also seek out tech help from Asus, but they just told me to download and install this drivers: https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin10/Chipset/Chipset_Intel_CherryTrail_T_Win10_64_VER102.zip?_ga=2.42119907.737913105.1575878632-602675098.1546953198&_gac=1.48541268.1573223144.CjwKCAiAwZTuBRAYEiwAcr67OU7jIc4BLeohVXec9EmJ7zgweD0X0DRtn_USkgFPUS_5MwvnYCqUcxoCy6wQAvD_BwE https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/ASUS_Device_Activation/ASUS_Device_Activation_Win10_64_VER1050.zip?_ga=2.42119907.737913105.1575878632-602675098.1546953198&_gac=1.4854126